# Why does Google include a lot of icons inside their result page's logo? Is it an optimization technique?

Tags: javascript, html, image, image-processing, optimization

A moment ago I found out that the Google logo image of the results page contains a lot of icons (you can see this simply by dragging or inspecting the logo).

I don't think this is a bug so, what's its purpose?
Is it an optimization technique?  If so, how it works?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a CSS sprite. It is a performance technique as requesting many small images is costly as it requires a lot of HTTP requests. This only requires one.

[Here](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) is a short guide on how to make and use them.

> In short: CSS Sprites are a means of combining multiple images into a
>   single image file for use on a website, to help with performance.